# When are template parameter packs deduced as empty?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

Consider the following examples ([Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4457bbda7ce97674)):

```
template <class... T> struct S { using type = int; };

template <class... T>
void f(typename S<T...>::type) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(T) == 0);
}

template <class... T>
void g(typename S<T...>::type, S<T...>*) {}

int main() {
    f(42);
    g(42, nullptr);
}
```

GCC and Clang are both happy with the call to `f`, but not the call to `g`.

In the call to `f`, although `T...` appears in a non-deduced context, it ends up being deduced as empty. This seems to be due to [[temp.arg.explicit]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#4):

> ... A trailing template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]) not otherwise deduced will be deduced as an empty sequence of template arguments. ...

In the call to `g`, however, the fact that `T...` additionally *appears in a deduced context*, which causes deduction to be *attempted and failed*, seems to cause `g` to become non-viable. There seems to be no "fallback" to `T...` being empty once deduction has been attempted and failed.

- Is this behaviour intended? If so, why?
- If so, was it intended that the "not otherwise deduced" wording specifies this behaviour? (*i.e.*, it implies that the empty fallback only occurs if the pack appears in no deduced contexts)
- If so, is this wording clear enough? It seems a plausible alternative reading of "not otherwise deduced" is "either deduction was not done, or deduction was attempted and failed".

Comment: I think this is intended, because I cannot think of a possible alternative reading.

Comment: Completely without templates: `void f(int*) { } void f(double*) { } void g() { f(nullptr); }` – appears consistent to me (which of the many overloads produced by the template would we actually want to use?). I'd rather turn the question around: *What's the reasoning for allowing empty template argument deduction in non-deduced contexts?*

Comment: @Aconcagua Probably the same reason that the default template argument is taken in a non-deduced context https://godbolt.org/z/XjG_D1

Comment: @Rakete1111 So empty argument list would be considered as 'default'? Appears reasonable somehow...

Comment: @L.F. I suggested an alternative reading in the last bullet point: it could include cases where deduction was attempted but failed.

Comment: @Brian Indeed.  "Not otherwise deduced" can mean "no deduction at all" or "no successful deduction".

Comment: @Brian It seems that nullptr_t is a dead end for the type inference system. It has no way to go from nullptr to "a pointer to some sort of S". As a possible workaround, you can provide a hint: template <class... T> S<T...>*  sp_conv(nullptr_t zp) { return zp; } ; and then call g(42, sp_conv(nullptr)); this works with GCC v8 and Clang v7.

Comment: @jpmarinier I understand why deduction fails. That wasn't what I was asking.

Answer (score 4):

> ... A trailing template parameter pack ([temp.variadic]) not otherwise
> deduced will be deduced as an empty sequence of template arguments.
> ...

It could be enough to say that the *not otherwise deduced* is not a clause that should somehow or automagically relax some other rules or actually it is has nothing to do with why it's malformed (contrary to what I think you imply).

This *other rule* is perhaps best demonstrated by another very simple example:

```
template<class T>
void f(T, T){};

int main() {
    f(int{42},short{42});
}
```

The above fails to compile. Why? Because even while `short` converts to `int` seamlessly (*promotion*), it is not the same type.

Additionally since `nullptr` just has the somewhat *plain* type of `std::nullptr_t` - it is very ill-suited to participate in template argument deduction *at all*.

So let's forget about non-deduced context for a moment, and try with deduced one:

```
template <class... T>
void g(S<T...>*, S<T...>* ) {}

int main() {
    S<> s1;
    g(&s1, nullptr);
}
```

*or if you prefer, just*

```
int main() {
    S<> s1;
    g(&s1, 0);
}
```

and both fail for the same reason.

Now, if you would like to allow conversion - then use an identity template - and this even works for the non-deduced context!

For your case, the example could look like ([c++2a](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a)):

```
template <class... T>
void g(typename S<T...>::type, std::type_identity_t<S<T...> >*) {}

int main() {
    f(42);
    g(42, nullptr);
}
```

Which is valid. (note if you don't have have [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) just write the identity template yourself)

As stated in a [comment](/q/57174400#comment100862385_57174400), turning the question around could perhaps lead to a more interesting question ?

*What's the reasoning for allowing empty template argument deduction in non-deduced contexts?*

Comment: It sounds like you're making the point that overall deduction only succeeds when deduction succeeds at every deduced context for a given template parameter (or template parameter pack); if there are two deduced contexts for the same template parameter, and deduction fails at one of the two contexts, then the parameter is not deduced according to the other context; instead the deduction simply fails. However, I don't think you answered my question. Could one not read "not otherwise deduced" as covering this situation? The pack was, in a sense, not deduced, since deduction failed.

Comment: I guess you are right if read in vacuum it is *somewhat* unclear. Perhaps im predisposed, but I do read it like "Not otherwise deduced" != "deduction was attempted and failed" and "Not other wise deduced" == "deduction was not actually done". Thats mainly due to the "Otherwise" in there. It's not unclear but theres perhaps room for improvement.

Comment: @darune I would question why standard would use  the chiefly British "other wise" ( meaning "in other way")